# How to swap assets on-chain on any popular DEX?

Tags: solana-program, rust, swap, raydium, dex

I need to create a Program with a function `swap_on_dex(...)` which will accept an input token with an amount, a target wallet address and execute a swap for SOL (optionally, for other token) on **any popular** DEX: Orca, Raydium, Serum, Jupiter.

I haven't found any info about the topic. I've looked into Raydium which is the most popular DEX, yet to no avail.

There're, however, examples of how to execute this on the client side, that is, off-chain. But I need it within a Program - **on-chain**, in Rust.

How to do it? Any simple example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calling another contract from within an on-chain contract on Solana is referred to as CPI (cross program invocations). You can read more about it [here](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/cpi.html).

Here are the rust bindings for Raydium's contracts https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/tree/master. Orca CPI crate: https://github.com/orca-so/whirlpool-cpi.

Comment: Thansk. How to approach this? Is there any simple example?